# How to combine diffs of previous commits in Git

Tags: git

I started working on an issue that I thought would only take one commit, then I started to include other features and UI changes with this issue and it ended up being 4 commits or so. I want to see a merge of all the diffs of those commits without overlaps at once and I'm not sure if such a git command exists.

I tried `git show sha sha sha sha` but it just shows all the diffs not a merge of the diffs like I want.

For example if commit 1 added a line and commit 2 removed that same line, the merged diff should not even mention this line of code, similarly for the same line being modified by commit 1 and 2 should only show the final edit of commit 2.

It is important to keep in mind that there are several commits between the 4 commits in question since multiple users are committing to the same repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wanted to reply that you can just use a simple [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) but then I read your last sentence.

> It is important to keep in mind that there are several commits between the 4 commits in question since multiple users are committing to the same repository.

This is the crucial point.

As far as I know it's impossible to "*filter*" changes from specific commits from a diff. You can view the changes of each commit separately, but you seem to know this.

Nevertheless, if you truly want to get a diff of the changes, and only the changes introduced by this commits, there is a way to make that happen.

---

Create a temporary **branch** which points to the **first commit** you want to diff.

```
git branch tmp <first-commit-for-diff>
git checkout tmp
```

Then use [`git cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to sequentially apply the changs of all further commits, you want to include in your diff.

```
git cherry-pick <second-commit-for-diff>
git cherry-pick <third-commit-for-diff>
# And so on
```

*It's possible that this will result in conflicts, especially if later commits rely on changes introduced by commits you didn't `cherry-pick`.*

After this you can simply diff the branch with the **parent** of the **first commit**.

```
git diff tmp <first-commit-for-diff>^    # The trailing ^ tells git to use the parent
```

This should result in the desired "combined diff".

---

To ease this process in the future, I would suggest using a branch from the very beginning (e.g. called `feature/abc`). Then you can continue to work on your own changes, without being bothered by changes introduced by other users.

After you finished your work, you can merge this branch into the development branch.

This is in general a very common workflow in git.

Comment: i am definitely going to start branching in the future to ease this process, my mistake was thinking that a feature / issue would only take 1 commit, thanks for the advice

Comment: @LoganMurphy A very common workflow is [gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). I can highly recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

I guess what you really want is the diff of a set of particular files you worked on without unrelated changes in different parts of the repository. Assuming `commit1` is the first commit and `commit2` the last and `[<path>...]` is the list of files/directories you worked on you can simply use

```
git diff commit1^..commit2 -- [<path>...]
```

to see the combined changes. If there were other changes in the same paths which you don't want to see you might be out of luck anyway, since some of your commits might be based on these changes.

Comment: This worked for me! I just wanted to see the combined diff of a few commits on a shared branch